# Подключение callback-функции из другого js-файла

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую.

Есть 1-й js-файл со следующим кодом:

```
(function($) {
$(function() {

    function myfunction(callback) {
        // тут jQuery-код
        callback();
    }

    myfunction(showAlert);

});
})(jQuery);
```

Есть 2-й js-файл со следующим кодом:

```
(function($) {
$(function() {

    function showAlert() {
        alert('Hello!');
    }

});
})(jQuery);
```

Вопросы:

1. Как сделать, чтобы функция `showAlert()` запускалась из 2-го файла? Сейчас выдается ошибка: `Uncaught ReferenceError: showAlert is not defined.
2. Как сделать, чтобы ошибки `Uncaught ReferenceError: showAlert is not defined` также не было в том случае, когда нет второго js-файл (т.е. когда функция `showAlert()` нигде не прописана)?

Т.е. по сути мне нужна возможность запуска callback-функции из любого другого js-файла, подключенного к сайту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблемы номер 1 надо функцию положить в глобальный объект. Например, так:

```
window.showAlert = function() {
    alert('Hello!');
};
```

Такой подход допустим, если ваш модуль экспортирует всего одну функцию. Иначе лучше экспортировать один объект, в котором будет лежать все остальное:

```
window.Module2 = {
    showAlert : function() {
        alert('Hello!');
    },
};
```

Теперь по пункту 2. В принципе, можно сделать как-то вот так:

```
Module2 && Module2.showAlert();
```

Иными словами, проверяем существование и вызываем при наличии. Если такой вариант не понятен, то можно использовать вот этот:

```
if (Module2) {
    Module2.showAlert();
}
```

Но первый вариант заметно короче и удобней. Советую все-таки использовать его - в javascript это довольно популярный трюк для работы с элементами, которых может не быть.

Но скажите, почему вообще допустима ситуация, когда чего-то важного для выполнения кода на странице не оказывается? Вероятнее всего, проблема на самом деле архитектурная. Код, в котором слишком много подобных конструкций, называется макаронным. Рекомендую почитать про шаблоны проектирования, позволяющие уменьшить связность кода.

К примеру, тут мог бы помочь паттерн "Публикация/подписка".

Comment: `if (Module2.showAlert) {
    Module2.showAlert();
}`
Если `Module2.showAlert` число больше нуля, или непустая строка, проверка тоже пройдет. Обязательно проверять на тип переменной нужно!

Comment: Подразумевается, что код полностью свой и ничего лишнего там быть не может. Но ошибка тут все равно есть, только немного другая. Спасибо что напомнили.

Comment: Спасибо! Это решение сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Вы нарушаете законы области видимости.
Помещая что-то в самовызываюшуюся функцию `(function() {})()` вы создаете новую область видимости. Области идут сверху в низ, но не с низу вверх. Поэтому ваша функция видит,все что находится на уровень выше, но вот этот уровень выше в ф-цию заглянуть не сможет. От сюда и ошибка, что ваш callback не определен. Вашу проблему не решить, не вынося хоть-что в глобальную область видимости.
Что бы проверить можно ли вызывать функцию, можно сделать так:

```
func && typeof func == 'function' && func()
```

Не совсем явно, поэтому расскажу:

1. Проверяем, определенна ли переменная ( в данном случае undefined она или нет)
2. Проверяем является ли переменная функцией
3. Выполняем функцию ( в js ленивая логика, если где-то запнется перед последней проверкой, дальше даже не пойдет )

На счет главного вопроса: либо создайте один глобальный модуль, аля Callbacks, там записывайте все колбеки ( доступ только через объект Callbacks)

```
var Callback = {}
Callback.showAlert = function () {};

showAlert() // ошибка
Callback.showAlert() // все работает
```

Либо выносите переменные в глобальную область видимости ( либо под одну самовызываюшуюся ф-цию)

Comment: Куда нужно вставлять `func && typeof func == 'function' && func()` применительно к моему коду?

Comment: @Dimox, там где хотите вызывать функцию, там и вставляйте эту проверку
`function myfunction(callback) {
        // тут jQuery-код
        callback && typeof callback== 'function' && callback();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Поместите её вне блока `function($){}`. Тогда она будет глобальной.

Comment: Да, я это уже пробовал и это сработало. Но мне нужно именно внутри `function($){}`, как в примере.